# How to use an overloaded function as an argument of function template?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I think everyone has experience working with a code like the following:

```
void fun(Type1&);
void fun(Type2&);
vector<Type1> vec;
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), fun);
```

Of course that won't compile, because it's not clear which function to be passed. And what's your commonly-used solution to the problem?

I know this will work:

```
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), (void(*)(Type1&))fun);
```

But any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use template function:

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T&);
// specialize fun for Type1 and Type2
...
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), fun<Type1>);
```

The better way is to use functor with template `operator()`:

```
struct fun
{
  template<typename T>
  void operator()(T&) const;
};
...
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), fun()); // T for operator() will be deduced automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to second Kirill's answer. If fun() functions are implemented very similarly (same code involving different types), it's a good idea to rewrite them as one single template function. As an additional plus, you would get a possibility to elegantly specify the function you need.

It's usually recommended to use the C++ equivalent to the C-style type cast:

```
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), reinterpret_cast<void(*)(Type1&)>(fun));
```

Even more appropriate is to use static_cast in this case:

```
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), static_cast<void(*)(Type1&)>(fun));
```

since we want to hint the compiler to the proper type.

Although much more verbose, it's better simply for code maintenance reasons -- it's easier to search for such constructs in the code than for C-style type casts.

There is also a possibility to avoid using type casts in favor of an explicit template argument specification:

```
for_each<std::vector<A>::iterator, void(*)(Type1&)>(vec.begin(), vec.end(), fun);
```

-- although it's not very big improvement from the original code. As you can see, you have to explicitly specify the first template parameter as well.

Comment: Well... It's still type casting.

Actually I see this question on another site. I didn't come up with a good solution, except type casting. So I want to see if there is really a elegant method to do it.

However, I will always prefer function object or lambda expr in such a situation. :)